# JavaScript Failure

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I try to learn how to write Javascript but I have found a problem either so basic I would never think about it or so complicated that I lack the knowladge to find it.

I am Using NetbeansIDE 8.0 .

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <title>Objekt Navigator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Something<br/>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Text");
        alert("Bla bla");
    </script> 
    Else<br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the compiled page is opened it will only display "Something" and "Else" but nothing of the script.
If I remove "document.write("Text");" it will show the alert but there is no wrong wording in "document.write".
I really need one (or more) pointers to understand this.

Comment: Everything is right with your html. If you open it (e.g. Firefox) everything looks good. What kind of browser you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Pointer 1:

Don't use `document.write`.  Really.  It has been archaic and obsolete for at least 15 years, if not 20.  Use regular `DOM` methods.

Whatever tutorial you found that in, choose something else.

Pointer 2: Don't use XHTML.   Use the [`HTML5` Doctype](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/doctype.htm).  The XHTML one does some very weird things with JavaScript -- IF the file is being served as XHTML.

Lastly: your code works just fine for me.  If this is not the exact code that you are using in your tests, look at your console.log to see if you have an error somewhere.